# In flutter how to create dynamic column and row both (according to data column ) in datatable

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, dynamic-columns

In Flutter I Want to dynamic column in my Data Table because from database every time I get different number() of column.
how I create Anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a `StatefulWidget` that wraps your DataTable, you can define
`List<DataColumn> dataColumns;` in your state.
And every time you get your source data from API/calculations/or somewhere. You can fill this `dataColumns` list from source data and invoke `setState`.

Let's say you fetch Column names form database and put it in a `List<String> columnNames=['Name','Surname','Phone','Adress'];`

```
setState(() {
   dataColumns=columnNames.map((string)=>DataColumn(label: Text(string)).toList();   
 }); 
    

DataTable(
          columns: dataColumns,
          ////....
    
    )
```

Comment: " dataColumns "  how i create this variable , please one example

Comment: because , i get error type      '!rows.any((DataRow row) => row.cells.length != columns.length)': is not true.

Comment: type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DataColumn>'

Comment: Please check answer, I edited to make it more clear.